# Increasing an integer through a time delay

Tags: c, teensy

I'm producing a game in C on a microprocessor. The score is controlled by how long you can survive; the score increases by 1 every 3 seconds. The score is an integer which is declared globally, but displayed from a function.

```
int score = 0;//globally declared

void draw_score(int score_d)
{
    char score_draw[99];
    sprintf(score_draw,"%d", score_d);
    draw_string(score_draw, 9, 0);
}
```

I was thinking of a function which just increases the score by one with a delay on it, however that has not worked.

```
void score_increaser(int score)
{
    score++;
    _delay_ms( 3000 );
}
```

Does it need to be in a while loop? the function itself would go into a while loop in the main anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is pass by value.

`score_increaser()` as shown in your question increases just a **copy** of what is passed in.

To fix this there are (mainly) two options:

1. As `score` is defined globally, do not pass in anything:

   ```
   void score_increaser(void) {
     score++;
     _delay_ms( 3000 );
   }
   ```

   This modifes the globale `score` directly.
2. Pass in the address of `score` and de-reference it inside the function

   ```
   void score_increaser(int * pscore) {
     (*pscore)++;
     _delay_ms( 3000 );
   }
   ```

   Call it like this

   ```
   ...
   score_increaser(&score);
   ...
   ```

A 3rd, a bit more complex, approach (which assumes signals are supported on the target platform) would

1. setup a signal and a referring handler, then
2. setup a timer to fire a signal every N seconds.
3. This signal then is handled by the handler, which in turn
4. increases the global `score` and
5. starts the timer again.

This might look like:

```
#include <signal.h> /* for signal() and sig_atomic_t */
#include <unistd.h> /* for alarm() */


#define DURATION (3) /* Increase score every 3 seconds. */

sig_atomic_t score = 0;


void set_alarm(unsigned);

void handler_alarm(int sig)
{
  ++score;
  set_alarm(DURATION);
}

void set_alarm(unsigned duration)
{
  signal(SIGALRM, handler_alarm);
  alarm(duration);
}


int main(void)
{
  set_alarm(DURATION);

  ... /* The game's codes here. */
}
```

This latter approach has the advantage that your game's code does not need to take care about increasing `score`. `score` is just increased every 3 seconds as long as the program runs.

Comment: Good answer, but wouldn't `#include <unistd.h>` limit the use of this to Unix platforms only?

Comment: @WedaPashi: Well, `unistd.h` might be easily replaced by any other header providing the prototype for `alarm()`. The same applies to the signalling stuff.

Comment: Whilst complex, this solution will work best in the long run and be compatible with other running functions. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest against using signals.  Mostly because, when programming without an OS, signals take a lot of code space that can be better utilized for other purposes.   However, a hardware timer is (almost) always available so suggest using the hardware timer

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a timer interrupt. Configure the timer to 3 seconds.

```
volatile int score = 0; //global

void Intr_Init(peripheral_t per)
{
    //Initialize the timer interrupt
}

void draw_score(int score_d)
{
    char score_draw[99];
    sprintf(score_draw,"%d", score_d);
    draw_string(score_draw, 9, 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    Intr_Init(TIMER);
    while(1)
    {
        //Code that makes your game run
        draw_score(score);
    }
}

ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    //clear disable interrupt
    score++;
    //enable interrupt
}
```

In embedded, you should rely on Timers for better time critical tasks and accuracy. The way Delay routines are implemented is usually a loop or a up/down counter. Whereas a timer is usually based on counting SysTicks.
Another major advantage of Interrupts is that you let processor do its tasks all the while instead of making it block in a delay loop.

Answer (score 0):

`score` is global value then do not need to pass it in function if that function has access to that global space

```
void score_increaser() {
score++;
_delay_ms( 3000 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need parameter for the score since it's declared globally..

```
//global 
int score = 0;

void score_increaser()
{
   _delay_ms(3000);
   score++;
}
```

calling is like: `score_increaser();` should do the work.. 
i suggest you check for `score` in any other line/function.. maybe you have redeclared it or accidentally changed the value..

hope this helped..

Comment: this, to work, requires a pre-emptive OS.  for a 'bare metal' project this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

here is a good method for handling the score.

in the 'start game' function,

```
clear 'score' to 0
setup a timer: 
--to expire once each 3 seconds 
--enable the automatic reload feature, 
--enable the timer interrupt
--enable the timer counter
```

in the timer interrupt handler function

```
--increment 'score'
--clear the timer interrupt pending flag
```

in the 'end game' function

```
disable the timer counter
disable the timer interrupt
display the 'score' value
```